Let $G$ a lie group and $\varphi:G\times G\to G$ given by $(g,h)\to ghg^{-1}$. what is $(d\varphi)_{(g,h)}(X_g,X_h)$.
Let $G$ a lie group and $\varphi:G\times G\to G$ given by $(g,h)\to ghg^{-1}$.
I want to know the derivative of $\varphi$ in the simplest way. I mean, I want to know what is $(d\varphi)_{(g,h)}(X_g,X_h)$.
I already know that the multiplication $\theta:G\times G\to G$ given by $(g,h)\to g\cdot h$ is smooth and its differential is $(d\theta)_{(g,h)}(X_g,X_h)=(dL_g)_h(X_h)+(dR_h)_g(X_g)$.
Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Consider the composition $\varphi = \theta \circ \psi$, where $\psi:G\times G\to G\times G$ is defined by
$$\psi(g,h) = (gh, g^{-1}).$$
Let $i:G\to G$ be the inversion $i(g) = g^{-1}$. Then
$$d\psi_{(g,h)}(X_g,Y_h) = ((dL_g)_h(Y_h) + (dR_h)_g(X_g),di_g(X_g)). $$
So we need to calculate $di_g(X_g)$. Since $g \mapsto \theta(g,i(g))=e$, we have
$$ 0 = d\theta_{(g,i(g))}(X_g, di_g(X_g)) = (dL_g)_{i(g)} (di_g(X_g)) + (dR_{i(g)})_g(X_g),$$
so
$$ di_g(X_g) = -(dL_g)_{i(g)}^{-1} ((dR_{i(g)})_g(X_g)) = - (dL_{i(g)})_e ((dR_{i(g)})_g(X_g)). $$
Hence
\begin{align*}
d\varphi_{(g,h)}(X_g, Y_h) &= (dL_{gh})_{i(g)}(di_g(X_g)) + (dR_{i(g)})_{gh}((dL_g)_h(Y_h) + (dR_h)_g(X_g))\\
&=- (dL_{ghg^{-1}})_{e} \circ (dR_{g^{-1}})_g(X_g) \\
&\quad \, + (dR_{g^{-1}})_{gh}\circ (dL_g)_h(Y_h) \\
&\quad \, + (dR_{hg^{-1}})_{g}(X_g).
\end{align*}
